# Public Facing Kiosks use of Static or Dynamic IP addressing?

Tags: ipv4, dhcp

I'm trying to maintain around 40 kiosks using Windows Server 2012. The kiosks run Windows 8.1 Pro. In addition to the use of Active Directory Directory Services on these kiosks, I am trying to assign IP addresses to these kiosks.

I would like to be able to monitor these kiosks using third party software and have all the kiosks be part of my single WS2012 Domain.

I've heard different opinions about using static addressing for kiosks and for using dynamic addressing.  Should I be using DHCP or will that affect my ability to be able to monitor and perhaps RDP into these kiosks.

What are the pros and cons of each in my scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are logging into these via RDP and have DHCP configured for their IP's then you need to have appropriate DNS / name services configured, so when/if the IP changes you can still access the kiosks. Another option with DHCP would be have mac-IP bindings on your DHCP server so that each host always receives the same IP and have these reserved.